# (VUEJS) Access methods from Axios inside created

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, youtube-data-api

I have just a simple error which is confusing me almost 3 weeks.

my question is about, I want to return string from methods "idvideo" at the end of my axios API url, but nothing is happen.

as you can see on my code below.

I have been searching for solution and try an error for many times, but still never found any best answer that can help me out.

```
    export default {

        data() {
          return {
            errors: [],
            videos: [],
            items: []

          }
        },

        methods: {
          idvideo: function() {
            const data = this.items
            const result = data.map((item) => {
              return {
                fetchId: item.snippet.resourceId.videoId
              };
            }).sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);

            var i, len, text;
            for (i = 0, len = result.length, text = ""; i < len; i++) {
              text += result[i].fetchId + ",";
            }
            var x = text.slice(0, -1);
            return(x);
          }

        // Fetches posts when the component is created.
        created() {

          // Ini adalah API utk playlist yang dipilih
          axios.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLjj56jET6ecfmosJyFhZSNRJTSCC90hMp&key={YOUR_API_KEY}")
          .then(response => {
            // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
            this.items = response.data.items
          })
          .catch(e => {
            this.errors.push(e)
          }),

          // Ini adalah API utk data yang dipilih
          axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&key={YOUR_API_KEY}&id='+this.idvideo())
        .then(response => {
            // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
          this.videos = response.data.items
          })
          .catch(e => {
            this.errors.push(e)
          })
        },
        }
```

I really appreciate any kind of solutions that can help me out. If you guys have best way to implement this function, let me know.

Sorry for my bad english and any mistakes. This is my very second time post question in this platform.

Thank you very much sir!

Comment: See if this helps. https://pastebin.com/AVFduFQB

Comment: Hey @Pradeepb ... Thank you for the solution. Why it isnt cross in my mind?. hehe. Very much thanks!

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, they are asynchronous requests, I have following solution in my mind.

Solution:

Move the next axios call within the first axios call. This is because, only after first call, the 'items' will be retrieved and then it will assigned to `this.items` So next axios call will have the required data from `idvideo()` function.

```
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        errors: [],
        videos: [],
        items: []

      }
    },

    methods: {
      idvideo: function() {
        const data = this.items
        const result = data.map((item) => {
          return {
            fetchId: item.snippet.resourceId.videoId
          };
        }).sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);

        var i, len, text;
        for (i = 0, len = result.length, text = ""; i < len; i++) {
          text += result[i].fetchId + ",";
        }
        var x = text.slice(0, -1);
        return(x);
      }

    // Fetches posts when the component is created.
    created() {

      // Ini adalah API utk playlist yang dipilih
      axios.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLjj56jET6ecfmosJyFhZSNRJTSCC90hMp&key={YOUR_API_KEY}")
      .then(response => {
        // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
        this.items = response.data.items

        // Ini adalah API utk data yang dipilih
      axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&key={YOUR_API_KEY}&id='+this.idvideo())
    .then(response => {
        // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
      this.videos = response.data.items
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
      })
    }
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
      }),
      ,
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to return axios.get in first `then`(which will return promise), so that next `then` can chain to it. Or is it not needed?

Comment: May be it can be done like that as well. But I am unaware of that solution :)